# align-items-start and justify-content-between without using flexbox

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, responsive

I have the following html code and what I am trying to do is to align all the black boxes on the top of the container and make the whole container content responsive so when the window gets smaller if the images do not fit in the container, they move down and align themeselves just like justify content-between to the entire container. I have trouble with the middle image because it has 2 paragraphs bellow it and the black-box gets higher than the others black boxes. Also I am having trouble making it responsive. Can someone please help?

```
<html lang="el">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <div class="container menu-images">
            <div class="menu-img-div">
                <a href="Publications.html">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/2YdegoR_d.webp?maxwidth=760&fidelity=grand" class="menu-img" alt="Posts HPV">
                    <p>TEXT 1</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-img-div"><a href="Videos.html">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/2YdegoR_d.webp?maxwidth=760&fidelity=grand" class="menu-img" alt="videos HPV">
                    <p>TEXT 2</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-img-div"><a href="Information.html">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/2YdegoR_d.webp?maxwidth=760&fidelity=grand" class="menu-img" alt="Cheatsheet-Frame HPV">
                    <p>TEXT 3.1</p>
                    <p>TEXT 3.2</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-img-div">
                <a href="Poster.html">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/2YdegoR_d.webp?maxwidth=760&fidelity=grand" class="menu-img" alt="poster HPV">
                    <p>TEXT 4</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-img-div">
                <a href="Questions.html">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/2YdegoR_d.webp?maxwidth=760&fidelity=grand" class="menu-img" alt="Συχνές-ερωτήσεις HPV">
                    <p>TEXT 5</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
Also here is my css

.menu-img-div {
    display: inline-block;
}
.menu-images {
    max-width: 1324px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is how the container looks on desktop:

[IMGUR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGP9A.png)

and on mobile:

[IMGUR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3gLk.png)

then why don't you just use the grid system? (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/) it's much easier:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-12 col-md-4">
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-12 col-md-4">
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-12 col-md-4">
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have 5 boxes not 3. In your example you are using columns but the i want to fit all 5 boxes in a row for a large screen but the max number of columns in bootstrap is 12 so I can not devide 12 with 5